# PostgreSql na linha de comando do Windows - "psql"

Tags: postgresql

Bom dia, estou tentando aprender um pouco de postgreSql e vejo alguns vídeos onde usam comandos com a tag "psql", porém já baixei postgre e quando dou um comando com "psql" no começo ele fala que o comando não existe, alguém sabe como ativar o comando interno "psql"?

Comment: Isso depende do seu sistema operacional.

Comment: Qual o seu sistema operacional? Qual o instalador você utilizou?

Comment: uso Windows, e eu baixei o que tinha no site do postgre, baixei pelo enterprisedb

Comment: O instalador da EnterpriseDB deveria ter instalado o psql.

Comment: @anonimo o do site oficial também, mas aqui apesar de haver por algum motivo não criou o Path, o programa esta lá... eu não tinha reparado que era o enterprisedb, mas creio que possa ser conflito com uma versão anterior instalada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendo Windows, pelo [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/463104/postgresql-na-linha-de-comando-psql#comment877931_463104), depois de baixar via https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ e instalar, se o instalador não gerou o caminho no PATH (variaveis de ambiente) do Windows então terá que fazer manualmente, procure o caminho aonde instalou o PostgreSQL, exemplos:

```
C:\Programs and Files\PostgreSQL\12\
```

Ou algo como:

```
C:\Bancos\PostgreSQL\12\
```

No caso uso a versão 12, dependendo da versão vai só mudar o nome da pasta, então adicione "bin", ficando:

```
C:\Programs and Files\PostgreSQL\12\
```

Isso se você tiver instalado em `Programs and Files` se for outro lugar é óbvio que não deve copiar o que esta acima, é só para ter uma ideia, ficará assim:

```
C:\Programs and Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
```

Então copie esse caminho e vá nas **variáveis de ambientes** do Windows, vá em <kbd>Computador/
Meu Computador</kbd> dentro do explorer:

> [image: computador no explorer.exe]

Clique em <kbd>propriedades</kbd> para abrir o <kbd>Sistema</kbd> e no sistema clique em <kbd>Configurações avançadas de sistema</kbd>

> [image: Configurações avançadas de sistema]

Na janela <kbd>propriedades de sistema</kbd> clique em <kbd>variáveis de ambiente</kbd>

> [image: propriedades de sistema > variáveis de ambiente]

Na parte de baixo em <kbd>variáveis de ambiente</kbd> procure por <kbd>Path</kbd> e clique duas vezes com o mouse, ou selecione e vá no botão editar:

> [image: Path em variáveis de ambiente]

Ao abrir a janela clique em <kbd>novo</kbd>

> [image: novo valor em path]

Então cole o caminho de onde esta instalado o seu postgresql+bin (exemplo: `C:\Programs and Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`)

> [image: caminho do postgresql no Path]

Depois de feito isso faça o logoff e logon ou reinicie o Windows (acho que não precisa, ao menos aqui eu só fecho o cmd ou semelhante).

Pronto, o pgsql estará disponível via cli

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, resolveu meu problema!